# C# Sockets performance? issues when waiting for a response from a server

Tags: sockets, c#-4.0

I am currently a bit curious as to the following:

When trying to request a page from a server, it usually would take a few seconds to do this, one could confirm this via the webbrowser or w/e.

I tried to do this with sockets:

```
            string pData = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                       "Host: www.google.com\r\n" +
                       "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1\r\n" +
                       "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n" +
                       "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n" +
                       "Accept-Encoding: deflate\r\n" +
                       "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n" +
                       "Keep-Alive: 115\r\n" +
                       "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
        string[] a = CreateSocketRequest("www.google.com", 80, pData, 4);
        Console.WriteLine(a[0] + "\r\n" + a[1]);
```

**Note:** the call to CreateSocketRequest returns a string array with the headers in index 0 and content in index 1. Also, the code behind it works perfectly fine.

Anyway, the funny thing with the above request packet is that when the request is made there seems to be no response, in fact, one would need to pause the debugging for a while and then resume the program in order to see the response written to the console.

So it took me like insane amount of hours to find the culprit:

```
HTTP/1.1
```

In all of my amazement and all of the time wasted, one would for example need to change that to:

```
HTTP/1.0
```

And et voila the response is almost instantly written to the console, no delays, nothing, just as it should work.

My question would be: why does it take so long with HTTP/1.1 in the header whilst HTTP/1.0 does it instantaneously? I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on this matter or at least point me in the right direction.

**Note 1:** I forgot to mention, but, making the same requests using the TcpClient and NetworkStream results in the same slow performance but the WebClient did it instantly (did not test using HttpWebRequest).

**Note 2:** CreateSocketRequest method (not complete, but this should pretty much give you an idea):

```
    private const int BufferSize = 1024;
    public static string[] CreateSocketRequest(string host, int port, string requestData, int bufferMultiplication = 2)
    {
        Socket s = ConnectSocket(host, port);
        // Send the Data
        s.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestData));

        // Receive the Response
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList(BufferSize * (bufferMultiplication * 4));
        byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[BufferSize * bufferMultiplication];
        int bytes;

        try {
            while ( (bytes = s.Receive(receivedBytes, 0, receivedBytes.Length, SocketFlags.None)) > 0 )
                al.AddRange(bytes.Equals(BufferSize) ? receivedBytes : TakeBytes(receivedBytes, bytes));
        } catch ( SocketException se ) {
            // Write to log
            Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
        } finally {
            s.Close();
            s.Dispose();
        }

        receivedBytes = (byte[])al.ToArray(typeof(Byte));
    //
    // Convert to string and all that etc.
    //
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find `CreateSocketRequest`, but when using an `HttpWebRequest` I was able to get the response in 0.145 seconds:

```
HTTP Protocol Version: 1.1

Headers: Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Tue, 05 Jul 2011 06:16:09 GMT
Expires: -1
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=4bd33e8b133134b4:FF=0:TM=1309846569:LM=1309846569:S=ZT2NPRNq
yYBcgSmY; expires=Thu, 04-Jul-2013 06:16:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com,NID=
48=VwNz5I8Y_Pf51hGWUE38wq1YNb5-OOkPD-9V36tXHkLtitJea8pyO6MLB-wm6lpRmLDyDIiNuoklC
SldpfXFqNWKeKM6P4hIXudtUsEHiMiRICNf5ZUOmQbz1htShb8G; expires=Wed, 04-Jan-2012 06
:16:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Transfer-Encoding: chunked


Duration: 0.145 seconds
```

The code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com:80/");
    Console.WriteLine("HTTP Protocol Version: " + request.ProtocolVersion + "\n");

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine("Headers: \n" + response.Headers);
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("Duration: {0} seconds", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Like I said, I couldn't find the method `CreateSocketRequest` in any of the .NET 4.0 libraries, so if it's a method that you've written, then please provide the code for it. If it's something from another library, then I don't know if I can help you much. Additionally, I didn't go through all of the headers you're supplying in your request, but I assume that there is nothing specific in there that would cause the delay.

Comment: You are correct, CreatSocketRequest is a method I created and is nowhere to be found in the .NET libraries, I apologize for not making that clear (see main post for the code). Anyway, I see that you have tested it with the HttpWebRequest and that the result is instant. But my problem here is why is the HTTP/1.1 so slow on the Socket, TcpClient and NetworkStream? Whilst everything else works perfectly on the HttpWebRequest and WebClient? That is the problem that is bugging me so much.

Comment: Lith, I haven't had time to test your code, but I can guarantee you it has nothing to do with HTTP/1.1; also note that `Socket.Receive` is a blocking call. My example also uses HTTP 1.1 and it's not slow at all.

Comment: The problem is when using the Socket class the Socket.Receive is blocking too long. For example when I sent out a GET request with HTTP/1.1 it would take somewhere around the 3 minutes before it is finally writing the response to the console (note: when pausing the debugging you'll see that it hangs at Socket.Receive, as you said and as I am aware of it, because it is a blocking call). But why does it not end the blocking when everything is received? The curious thing is when using HTTP/1.0 is does not block for 3 mins, and the response is written instantly to the console.

Comment: Also, your example uses the HttpWebRequest, I have programs that use the HttpWebRequest and WebClient classes on sites with the HTTP/1.1 and they all perform magnificently. I have tested your code too and it works as you say it does and I know that too. But all fails when using the Socket class with HTTP/1.1 on Google for example, whilst the HTTP/1.0 does not. If you want I could even create a video showing what I mean.

Comment: You have to manually end the call, because a socket does not know when everything is received. All the socket knows is that it's got a connection to another endpoint and that it will be receiving/sending bytes. There is no way for the socket to know how many bytes it's supposed to receive and that's why the HTTP protocol specifies the content length when it sends you the header, thus the user is responsible for how many bytes they're requesting fromt he socket. Once you receive all the bytes, then simply don't call `Socket.Receive` again because it will block **indefinitely**!

Comment: If you want an asynchronous HTTP client, then take a look at the one [I've written on my blog](http://codesprout.blogspot.com/2011/04/asynchronous-http-client.html).

Comment: That is so weird though, shouldn't the int returned by the Socket.Receive inform you of the fact on whether more data is incoming or not? Also, again, me being annoying, this still does not explain why the HTTP/1.1 blocks indefinitely with the exact request headers as the HTTP/1.0, whilst the 1.0 does not block indefinitely. I will try to code the part to check on whether I have received all the bytes or not and test that out on the HTTP/1.1

Although I don't need an asynchronous HTTP client I will still take a good look at your code, thank you.

Comment: The documentation states that if "no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block until data is available." Like I said, I have not tried your code (swamped with work), but I don't see any reason why Socket.Receive would behave differently depending on the HTTP protocol. Sockets don't know anything about the HTTP protocol. The asynch http client is very fast, but I certainly wouldn't recommend that you use it unless you really need the speed boost.

Comment: Ah, yes, forgot that part about the Receive method, thanks for clearing that up. Well, neither do I, but it does behave differently, so differently that the impact is huge. Regrettably I have no use for the asynch http client as my requirements don't require/are not compatible with async. I want to thank you a bunch, really, appreciate the help a lot! I will do as you suggest by checking if I have received everything by comparing it against the content-length of the response and go on from there. Thanks again. =D.